# Multiplying multiple values by a single value in a loop

Tags: r

I am attempting to multiply a column of numbers representing daily precipitation amounts by the corresponding monthly precipitation amount of the same year. From the example below, this means multiplying every PPT value in January 1890 by the monthly PPT value for January 1890, i.e. multiplying 31 numbers from D.SIM by the same number from M.SIM, and then doing the same for all the remaining months and years in the record. Is there an easy way?

Many thanks.

**Dataset: D.SIM**

```
Day Month Year PPT
1 1 1890 2.4
2 1 1890 0.0
3 1 1890 3.6
```

**Dataset: M.SIM**

```
Year Jan Feb Mar ...
1890 78.5 69.6 62.1 ...
```

Comment: Do you have a sample data set to work with?

Comment: How do you post a sample data set?

Comment: One simple way would be by using `dput` function in R so that will produce reproducible code that we can then use. For example if I have a data frame in my R session called `df` I can use `dput(df)` and copy the output given by R into SO. This well then allow someone like myself to take some sample data to create the same df to work on. I would suggest using `dput(df)` in conjunction with `head` as well.

Comment: I ended up solving this by repeating the daily values by the amount of days in each months and then multiplying the two datasets. Probably not the most efficient method, but it works! Thanks for the help @amwill04 and sorry for wasting anyone's time.

Comment: It'll be much easier to get good answers (and it'll help future searchers who land here) if you formally provide inputs and expected outputs.
Even better if you use `dput` as mentioned above, but specifying the desired output in this sort of example is the key to getting help :-)

Comment: Thanks @mmuurr. I will bear this in mind in future. I hadn't worked out how to reproduce examples yet but will do so from now on.

Answer (score 0):

## Create loop to repeat daily values to align with monthly values

```
for (i in df){
    JAN <- data.frame(rep(df$Jan, each=31))
}
```

and then repeated for the other 11 months.